# Java Eclipse Maven Install error - certificate error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am very new to using Eclipse with Java/Maven, so bear with me because I'll probably ask this question incorrectly.  I am trying to do a Maven Install of an already existing project that will be used in a project I am creating.  I used Git to get the most recent version of this project (someone else created) and I run a Maven -> Update Project, checking Force update of snapshots and releases.  Works.  Do a Run As -> Maven Clean.  Success.  Do a Run As -> Maven Install, and it fails with the message below.

```
[INFO] Building DataSourceConfig 1.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] Downloading from : https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.9.4/commons-beanutils-1.9.4.pom
[INFO] Downloading from : https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/microsoft/sqlserver/mssql-jdbc/7.2.2.jre8/mssql-jdbc-7.2.2.jre8.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.049 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-02-26T14:17:58-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project datasourceconfig: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.sherwin.shercolor:datasourceconfig:jar:1.0: Failed to collect dependencies at commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.4: Failed to read artifact descriptor for commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.4: Could not transfer artifact commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:pom:1.9.4 from/to central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]
```

I have added a number of certificates to the cert store, which was the original problem, but some of these still refuse to connect - if I'm reading this right, it looks like a certificate problem.  Yet Eclipse is downloading jars/poms from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2 - and the certificate is store in cacerts.  In some cases, I have just downloaded the jar needed and stored in my repository on my own, but I shouldn't be having to do that - it should get the jars/poms for me.  Others in my group aren't having this issue because they've already had the project downloaded for some time, but I want to make the Maven Install work the way it should.

Here is my settings.xml (if needed)

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
                       <!--  localRepository
   | The path to the local repository maven will use to store artifacts.
   |
   | Default: ~/.m2/repository
   -->




   <activeProfiles>
    <!--make the profile active all the time -->
    <activeProfile>securecentral</activeProfile>

  </activeProfiles>
  <profiles>
      <profile>
      <id>securecentral</id>
      <!--Override the repository (and pluginRepository) "central" from the
         Maven Super POM -->
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </releases>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

</settings>
```

and my pom.xml from the project (don't know if you also need it, but figured I'd include it - with the names "hidden" for groupId and mainClass) -

```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.sherwin.shercolor</groupId>
    <artifactId>datasourceconfig</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>DataSourceConfig</name>
    <properties>

        <slf4j-log4j12.version>1.7.5</slf4j-log4j12.version>


    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j-log4j12.version}</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j-log4j12.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j-log4j12.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>-->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-dbcp2 -->
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>  -->

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-configuration2 -->
<!-- <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-configuration2</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
 -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.4</version>
</dependency>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.15</version>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>7.2.2.jre8</version>
        </dependency>
          <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0</version>
    </dependency>   


    </dependencies>

    <build>



        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>





            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.sherwin.shercolor.config.ExampleClass</mainClass>
                                </transformer>                          
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: The "PKIX.." exception means that the required certificates aren't present in your cacerts file. If you have multiple java installation, make sure the one used by maven has the required certificates. Does that only happen if you run maven within eclipse? Does it work correctly when invoking `mvn` from the command line?

Comment: By the way, you can use the ssl-poke utility to check if all required certificates are present. In example, try `java SSLPoke www.google.com 443` and/or `java SSLPoke repo1.maven.org 443` (code> https://gist.github.com/4ndrej/4547029

Comment: @Daniele I will try the ssl-poke.  Someone else suggested deleting my Maven related certs in the cert store and getting the most recent from both sites and adding again.

Comment: Got SSLPoke working @Daniele and this let me know my certificate is not valid, so I need to add the correct one.  Thanks!